# return Object.keys in a map got undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What's wrong with my loop below? I want to calculate the total_count and return [total, total] after some manipulation within a map, but I got undefined.

my `raw` data

```
const raw = [{
  "device_info": {
    "name": "cam1",
  },
  "age_range": {
    "0-10": {
      "age_range": "0-10",
      "total_count": 15,
      "male_count": 6,
      "female_count": 9
    },
    "11-20": {
      "age_range": "11-20",
      "total_count": 11,
      "male_count": 7,
      "female_count": 4
    },
    "21-30": {
      "age_range": "21-30",
      "total_count": 922,
      "male_count": 452,
      "female_count": 470
    }
  }
}, {
  "device_info": {
    "name": "cam2",
  },
  "age_range": {
    "0-10": {
      "age_range": "0-10",
      "total_count": 1,
      "male_count": 1,
      "female_count": 0
    },
    "11-20": {
      "age_range": "11-20",
      "total_count": 2,
      "male_count": 0,
      "female_count": 2
    },
    "21-30": {
      "age_range": "21-30",
      "total_count": 90,
      "male_count": 58,
      "female_count": 32
    }
  }
}]
```

Loop

```
const x = raw.map(obj => {
  return Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    let total = 0
    if (key === 'age_range') {
      total = Object.keys(obj.age_range).reduce((acum, innerKey) => {
        return acum + obj.age_range[innerKey].total_count
      }, 0)
      console.log(total)
    }
  });
})

console.log('x', x)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/19m3f7fs/1

Comment: Because [forEach doesn't return a value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value). You would need to set the value to a variable that is declared in a higher scope and return that

Comment: Running your code on chrome give me 948, 93. Where do you run your script ? Is `x` value the problem ? (as said by @PatrickEvans forEach dosen't return a value)

Comment: @Nolyurn sorry updated my code

Answer (score 2):

`Array#forEach` doesn't return anything, use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) instead:

```js
const x = raw.map(obj => {
  return Object.values(obj.age_range).reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.total_count, 0)
})
```

Working example:

```js
const raw = [{
  "device_info": {
    "name": "cam1",
  },
  "age_range": {
    "0-10": {
      "age_range": "0-10",
      "total_count": 15,
      "male_count": 6,
      "female_count": 9
    },
    "11-20": {
      "age_range": "11-20",
      "total_count": 11,
      "male_count": 7,
      "female_count": 4
    },
    "21-30": {
      "age_range": "21-30",
      "total_count": 922,
      "male_count": 452,
      "female_count": 470
    }
  }
}, {
  "device_info": {
    "name": "cam2",
  },
  "age_range": {
    "0-10": {
      "age_range": "0-10",
      "total_count": 1,
      "male_count": 1,
      "female_count": 0
    },
    "11-20": {
      "age_range": "11-20",
      "total_count": 2,
      "male_count": 0,
      "female_count": 2
    },
    "21-30": {
      "age_range": "21-30",
      "total_count": 90,
      "male_count": 58,
      "female_count": 32
    }
  }
}]

const x = raw.map(obj => Object.values(obj.age_range).reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.total_count, 0))

console.log(x)
```

Comment: I try to add a new property, device_id but why this break? https://jsfiddle.net/xbggz7kj/

Comment: You have to do it [differently](https://jsfiddle.net/t067j9a9/1). In your code, `acc` contains `0`, but you return an object. In the next iteration, `acc` will contain this object, and you try to add this object to the new `total_count`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that the raw.map returns whatever comes from Object.key(obj).forEach(...)

But for each is just an "iterator" function. It actually doesnt return anything.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

Change like this .define the total in first `map` varible and remove the return from `forEach`.ForEach not returning anything .And add the return satement only inside the first map.

```js
const raw = [{
  "device_info": {
    "name": "cam1",
  },
  "age_range": {
    "0-10": {
      "age_range": "0-10",
      "total_count": 15,
      "male_count": 6,
      "female_count": 9
    },
    "11-20": {
      "age_range": "11-20",
      "total_count": 11,
      "male_count": 7,
      "female_count": 4
    },
    "21-30": {
      "age_range": "21-30",
      "total_count": 922,
      "male_count": 452,
      "female_count": 470
    }
  }
}, {
  "device_info": {
    "name": "cam2",
  },
  "age_range": {
    "0-10": {
      "age_range": "0-10",
      "total_count": 1,
      "male_count": 1,
      "female_count": 0
    },
    "11-20": {
      "age_range": "11-20",
      "total_count": 2,
      "male_count": 0,
      "female_count": 2
    },
    "21-30": {
      "age_range": "21-30",
      "total_count": 90,
      "male_count": 58,
      "female_count": 32
    }
  }
}]

const x = raw.map(obj => {
    let total = 0
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (key === 'age_range') {
      total = Object.keys(obj.age_range).reduce((acum, innerKey) => {
        return acum + obj.age_range[innerKey].total_count
      }, 0)
    }
  });
       return total
})

console.log('x', x)
```