# return object within a reduce function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why the result of x is

> [object Object]12

Can't I return object in a reduce function? I know in map, filter I can return object, not sure what's wrong with my code below.

```js
const raw = [{
  "device_info": {
    "name": "nokia",
    "device_id": "123"
  },
  "age_range": {
    "0-10": {
      "age_range": "0-10",
      "total_count": 15,
      "male_count": 6,
      "female_count": 9
    },
    "11-20": {
      "age_range": "11-20",
      "total_count": 11,
      "male_count": 7,
      "female_count": 4
    }

  }
}, {
  "device_info": {
    "name": "iphone",
    "device_id": "456"
  },
  "age_range": {
    "0-10": {
      "age_range": "0-10",
      "total_count": 1,
      "male_count": 1,
      "female_count": 0
    },
    "11-20": {
      "age_range": "11-20",
      "total_count": 2,
      "male_count": 0,
      "female_count": 2
    }
  }
}]

const x = raw.map(obj => {
  return Object.values(obj.age_range).reduce((acc, obj2) => ({
    total_count: acc + obj2.total_count,
    device_id: obj.device_info.device_id
  }), 0)
})

console.log('x', x)
```

No clue what's wrong, need help.

Answer (score 1):

As I already [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45753004/5989584) to you: in the first iteration, `acc` contains 0, but you return an object. In the next iteration, `acc` will contain this object, and you try to add this object to the new `total_count`. I suggest this:

```
const x = raw.map(obj => {
  // calculate the total
  const total_count = Object.values(obj.age_range).reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.total_count, 0)
  // construct the object
  return { total_count, device_id: obj.device_info.device_id }
})
```

Working example:

```js
const raw = [{
  "device_info": {
    "name": "nokia",
    "device_id": "123"
  },
  "age_range": {
    "0-10": {
      "age_range": "0-10",
      "total_count": 15,
      "male_count": 6,
      "female_count": 9
    },
    "11-20": {
      "age_range": "11-20",
      "total_count": 11,
      "male_count": 7,
      "female_count": 4
    }

  }
}, {
  "device_info": {
    "name": "iphone",
    "device_id": "456"
  },
  "age_range": {
    "0-10": {
      "age_range": "0-10",
      "total_count": 1,
      "male_count": 1,
      "female_count": 0
    },
    "11-20": {
      "age_range": "11-20",
      "total_count": 2,
      "male_count": 0,
      "female_count": 2
    }
  }
}]

const x = raw.map(obj => {
  const total_count = Object.values(obj.age_range).reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.total_count, 0)
  return { total_count, device_id: obj.device_info.device_id }
})

console.log('x', x)
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t067j9a9/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize acc as an object and it should at least has the key `total_count`.

```js
const raw = [{
  "device_info": {
    "name": "nokia",
    "device_id": "123"
  },
  "age_range": {
    "0-10": {
      "age_range": "0-10",
      "total_count": 15,
      "male_count": 6,
      "female_count": 9
    },
    "11-20": {
      "age_range": "11-20",
      "total_count": 11,
      "male_count": 7,
      "female_count": 4
    }

  }
}, {
  "device_info": {
    "name": "iphone",
    "device_id": "456"
  },
  "age_range": {
    "0-10": {
      "age_range": "0-10",
      "total_count": 1,
      "male_count": 1,
      "female_count": 0
    },
    "11-20": {
      "age_range": "11-20",
      "total_count": 2,
      "male_count": 0,
      "female_count": 2
    }
  }
}]

const x = raw.map(obj => {
  return Object.values(obj.age_range)
    .reduce((acc, obj2) => {
      return {
        total_count: acc.total_count + obj2.total_count,
        device_id: obj.device_info.device_id
      }
    }, { total_count: 0 })
})

console.log('x', x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could switch the parts for constructing the object and counting the values by movint the counting inside of the object literal.

```js
const raw = [{ device_info: { name: "nokia", device_id: "123" }, age_range: { "0-10": { age_range: "0-10", total_count: 15, male_count: 6, female_count: 9 }, "11-20": { age_range: "11-20", total_count: 11, male_count: 7, female_count: 4 } } }, { device_info: { name: "iphone", device_id: "456" }, age_range: { "0-10": { age_range: "0-10", total_count: 1, male_count: 1, female_count: 0 }, "11-20": { age_range: "11-20", total_count: 2, male_count: 0, female_count: 2 } } }];
const x = raw.map(obj => ({
    total_count: Object.values(obj.age_range).reduce((acc, obj2) => acc +  obj2.total_count, 0),
    device_id: obj.device_info.device_id
}));

console.log(x);
```